# Datatables - convert from Mysql data: string to date object with moment.js

Tags: javascript, php, datatables, momentjs

I have date field as string (Text type) in mysql column called "date_fld".

It is in string format in mysql column, which looks like: 31.12.2021

Using PHP and JS / moment.js, I would want to convert this string format to date object to sort the DataTables header by actual date.

I am not sure, how to do that?

```
## Fetch records
      $this->db->select('*');
      $records = $this->db->get('data2')->result();

      $data = array();

      foreach($records as $record ){
         
          $data[] = array( 
            "#"=>$record->id,
            "Date"=>$record->date_fld
          ); 
      }

      ## Response
      $response = array(
          "draw" => intval($draw),
          "iTotalRecords" => $totalRecords,
          "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $totalRecordwithFilter,
          "aaData" => $data
      );

      return $response; 
    }
```

**DataTables:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY');
...

{ data: 'date_fld',
    render: function (data, type, row) {
      return moment(new Date(data)).format('DD.MM.YYYY');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have set up your JavaScript scripts correctly, you should only need to use the following line of code:

```js
$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY');
```

With that, you should not need to provide a render function, or any explicit reference to `moment.js` functions.

**Step-by-step:**

1. In the `<head>` of the HTML page, I include the following two scripts, after the standard jQuery and DataTables scripts:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.22/sorting/datetime-moment.js"></script>
```

The first script is for the `moment.js` library.

The second script is the DataTables [date-time plugin](https://datatables.net/blog/2014-12-18), which uses `moment.js`.

It is this second script which allows you to use `$.fn.dataTable.moment()`.

2. My test table looks like this:

```html
<table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%"></table>
```

3. My DataTables script is as follows:

```js
// This is my test data (you get your data from the database, of course):
var dataSet = [
  [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "21.12.2021", "$320,800" ],
  [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "20.12.2021", "$170,750" ],
  [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "31.01.2021", "$86,000" ],
  [ "Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "01.02.2021", "$103,600" ],
  [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "31.01.2020", "$433,060" ]
];
 
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY');

  $('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
      { title: "Name" },
      { title: "Position" },
      { title: "Office" },
      { title: "Extn." },
      { title: "Start date" },
      { title: "Salary" }
    ]
  } );
} );
```

**The Results**

Now I can see my dates displayed in the `DD.MM.YYYY` format - but they are sorted chronologically:

[image]

This works because the DataTables datetime plugin is doing two things for you:

(a) It uses the date format you provided (`DD.MM.YYYY`) and it auto-detects all the cells where this format is being used by your data. It converts these values from text to date objects for you. It uses your format, however, for displaying the date data in the table.

(b) the DataTables datetime plugin automatically builds a second version of each date value, specifically for sorting. Behind the scenes, it uses `moment().unix()` to build this sortable format of the date.

Therefore, you see the date displayed in in the table using your preferred format, but DataTables uses this other format when you sort on that column.

You don't need to use any `moment.js` functions, and you don't need to manipulate your date data in any explicit way for sorting. It is all taken care of, for you.

---

If you want to avoid using the DataTables plug-in, you can use a custom approach which does rely directly on `moment.js`:

1. Remove the `$.fn.dataTable.moment('DD.MM.YYYY');` line.
2. Change your date column to use a renderer:

```js
      { title: "Start date",
        render: function ( data, type, row ) {
          //console.log(data); // the raw date as a string
          var d = moment(data, 'DD.MM.YYYY'); // converted to a moment object
          var sortString = moment(d).format('YYYYMMDD'); // converted to a new string format
          //console.log(sortString);
          if ( type === 'display' || type === 'filter' ) {
            return data;
          } else {
            return sortString; // this version of the date will be used for sorting
          }
        }
      },
```

Now, we are building our own sortable version of the date, instead of leaving it to the DataTables plugin.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. So, you are correct, i do use those 2 js files and they are included like it should. So, I have some dates which now are now outputted as "invalid data". https://prnt.sc/xvga2m. You can see that it does not know how to render it if I just view them without the function: https://prnt.sc/xvgdkz

Comment: My guess is that it does try to render it backwards mm.dd.yyyy for some reason, and then it will output the invalid date where the months are over 12

Comment: That looks like days and months are being flipped. Those "invalid dates" probably are being interpreted with month values greater than 12. I can't tell from the code in the question why this is happening. My guess there is something in the source data which is causing the "auto-detect" to misinterpret the data. Are you confident that all your source data is consistently using the `DD.MM.YYYY` format?

Comment: Just out of interest, and for testing, I have updated my answer to include a version of the code which uses moment.js directly, instead of relying on the DataTables plugin. I am curious to see what happens with your data. You can also uncomment the console logging statements to see more details.

Comment: Yes, i think the same. Its is 100% true that the date format is like 31.12.2021 in sql database. The structure is as following: https://prnt.sc/xvi20g

Comment: OK - thank you. Are there any null values in your dates data? If so, how does that data show up when you pull it from the database? An empty string, or `null`, or something else?

Comment: Nope, all the columns have data, so there are no null values. Just searched the entire column. So now the "invalid date" is gone, but the scirpt now will sort it by last string like this if i try to sort it: https://prnt.sc/xvije0 and https://prnt.sc/xvipft

Comment: Uncomment those console logger statements and take a look at the values which are written to the console (hit F12 in your browser). See if they match what you expect - especially the `sortString` values.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/xvizpe - so it will output the year first, month and then day

Comment: Which is correct - since that is a sortable value.  In that case, there is some other reason why this data is not being used for sorting. But I cannot see why - sorry. I think your bet chance to get help is to create a [mre] - for example by creating a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: ok, ill try that. thank you. Ill later will post this here,